# Duplicating data in one cell as per repeat counter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I got into a bit of problem. I have data like this

```
   Date     Repeat

 7-Oct-2018    1
 8-Oct-2018    1
 9-Oct-2018    2
10-Oct-2018    2
11-Oct-2018    3
12-Oct-2018    2
13-Oct-2018    1
```

Now the result i want is a column where the date is repeated as per the repeat numbers, like this.

```
    Result

 7-Oct-2018
 8-Oct-2018
 9-Oct-2018
 9-Oct-2018
10-Oct-2018
10-Oct-2018
11-Oct-2018
11-Oct-2018
11-Oct-2018
12-Oct-2018
12-Oct-2018
13-Oct-2018
```

So how can i get this result. Please do help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to think of it for own study. For example, how about this sample formula? I think that there might be simpler formulas. So please think of this as one of them. When you use this, please put the following formula to a cell.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(A2:A8&",",B2:B8))),","))
```

This formula supposes that the values of `Date` and `Repeat` are put in `A2:A8` and `B2:B8`, respectively.

- Show repeatedly `Date` using `REPT()`. At this time, `,` is used as a delimiter.
- Join each cell with `,` using `JOIN()`.
- Split the cell with `,` using `SPLIT()`.
- Transpose the cells using `TRANSPOSE()`.

I think that you can also use `CONCATENATE()` and `TEXTJOIN()` for joining cells.

#### References:

- [REPT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en)
- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)

Comment: @Shijilal Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Also I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hello  there.. if you got time could you check this one too for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952904/lopping-through-a-set-of-values-in-google-sheet

Comment: @Shijilal Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry for my late reply. I saw it just now. I knew that a nice answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes got one solution. Will get in touch with you if any more issues. Thanks :)

Comment: if time permits,could you check these 2 questions please.
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964418/adding-blank-rows-in-a-set-of-data-in-google-sheets
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963740/looping-through-a-set-of-google-sheet-values

Comment: @Shijilal Thank you for your comments. I'm really sorry for my late response. I saw them just now. But some answers has already been posted, and it seems under discussing for resolving.